# Edit WordPress menu with add_filter()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use `add_filter()` to edit my menu and add two links ('login', 'logout'). However it never shows and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', '_s' ),
        'quick' => __( 'Quick Links', '_s' ),
    ) );

    add_filter( 'quick', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
    function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {

        if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'quick') {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Retailer Log Out</a></li>';
        }
        elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'quick') {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('/retailer-login') .'">Retailer Log In</a></li>';
        }
        return $items;
    }
```

This is from my functions.php, I wonder if someone knows the solution to my puzzle.

Thanks

Update:

I figured out part of the problem, this above code works fine, however my menu that displays this specific menu is inside the widget and for some reason it never gets the change. This menu is part of footer and its being loaded trough a widget.

Comment: You realise the first argument to the add_filter() function is the name of the existing filter to hook your function to, right? i.e probably one of the filters detailed here, unless you've already custom-built your own filter:http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Comment: I figured out the issue this works however my menu where this shows up is inside the widget and for some reason it never updates. So function is all good but for some reason widget is prevent it from showing the change

Comment: Maybe some part of the install hasn't loaded by the time your script is called?